# I there any default dashboard view to a particular user when he clicked on dashboard tab

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

is it possile to add default dashboard view appearing to a particular user when he click on  dashboard tab?

Comment: The default is whatever the user last viewed. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you login as a particular user and reach the dashboard tab and select the dashboard, then that dashboard will be displayed by default.

Also, that dashboard will be displayed in Home Page Components (top 3 components of the first row).

If you want to display default dashboard on home page then, click on Customize Page.

[image: Home page dashboard]

And select the dashboard from the drop-down.

[image: Dashboard snapshot]